# Reachability change notification works on iOS5 but not iOS4

Tags: ios

I incorporated the Reachability Code into my app and its been successfully working for a few months but so far I've only used it on iOS 5 devices.
However it doesn't work on an iOS 4 device.

The notification is registered for as follows:

```
 - (id) init
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(reachabilityChange:)
                                                 name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                               object:nil];

...


- (void) appBecameActive
{
...
self.reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:[url host]];
...
[self.reachability startNotifier];
```

stopNotifier is only getting called in dealloc

The problem is the ReachabilityCallback isn't getting called back when there is a reachabiity change, but I cannot see any reason why it should it ok on iOS5 but not iOS4.

This part of the code is unchanged from the Apple sample source code:

```
static void ReachabilityCallback(SCNetworkReachabilityRef target, SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags, void *info) {
#pragma unused (target, flags)
  NSCAssert(info != NULL, @"info was NULL in ReachabilityCallback");
  NSCAssert([(__bridge id)info isKindOfClass:[Reachability class]], @"info was wrong class in ReachabilityCallback");

  Reachability *noteObject = (__bridge Reachability *)info;
  // Post a notification to notify the client that the network reachability changed.
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:noteObject];
}
```

As mentioned, everything has been working fine for a long time when running on iOS5 devices, has anybody else encountered a similar issue in the past incorporating the reachability code into with iOS4?

Comment: Every time I work with Reachability I link the SystemConfiguration framework, are you doing that?

Comment: Thanks but, as I mentioned it works on iO5, which it wouldn't be able to without the framework.

Comment: ... [what did you just do to your question?](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10921145/revisions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the code in reachability that posts the notification to post it on the main thread, and see if that changes the behavior you're seeing.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:noteObject];
});
```

(assume you are listening for them on the main thread)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try, but won't be able to get round to it for a few days. If it reveals something interesting I'll post the bounty.

Comment: Can someone clarify why is this necessary? I wasn't receiving Reachability notifications in iOS 6 until I made the suggested modification. Is it a bug in the original Reachability code?

Comment: Notifications are per-thread. If the Reachability object lives on some thread other than the one you are listening on, you can't hear it's desperate, pleading cries for attention. But by making this change, you are making all the notifications send on a consistent thread (the main thread, via the main queue), which also gives you a consistent thread to listen on.

Answer (score 1):

`kReachabilityChangedNotification` is not a notification generated by a system framework.  It's generated by the Reachability sample code.  Sample code is intended to demonstrate concepts, not simply to get copied and pasted into an application as-is.  I suggest you start looking at the reachability code for the source of the problem rather than looking at the place that listens for the notification.

Comment: That's rather presumptuous to make the assumption the code was blindly copied and pasted.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint in your init method to make sure that your registration is being called.  If it is not, move it to viewDidLoad or make sure that your init method is called somewhere else.

I would do the same for appBecameActive.  Set a breakpoint for this and check to make sure that it's being initiated.  It should be called from here: applicationDidBecomeActive: in UIApplicationDelegate class.